# Jquery offset is returning the wrong value

Tags: jquery, offset

I have a collapsed sidebar (using bootstrap), and I'm trying to make sure the collapsed 
element is scrolled to whenever it is made visible.

In order to do that I'm using offset() by jQuery which returns 0 the first click
and returns the correct offset on the second click.

Here's my code:

```
    $.each($('[data-toggle="collapse"]'), function() {
        $(this).on("click", function() { 
            if ($(this).is('A')) { 
                event.preventDefault(); $(this).toggleClass("active");
                var x = $(this).attr("href");
                console.log($(x).offset().top)

            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: You might want to create a [JsFiddle](http://ww.jsfiddle.net) example with a current version of your code. It is quite hard to give a recommendation without seeing some more code.

Comment: I agree, it's best to make a JsFiddle. Give us as much info as possible in order to help you! It sounds like your collapsed element is set to `display: none` which has no offset value, because it doesn't exist in the page flow

Comment: @AdamBotley That's the answer, I missed that :) thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Items set to `display: none` are outside of the page flow, meaning they take up no space within the page. This means that whilst they are set to `display: none`, they have no offset values.

On the first click, the browser tries to find the offset, which is 0 and then shows the element. As soon as the element is displayed, an offset left/top value is given.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hnjU/)

Comment: Thanks would have never figured this out on my own!